# Cannot step into MVC Custom RequiredAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I cannot step into my custom RequiredAttribute.

I have followed this article [How to: Debug .NET Framework Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc667410.aspx)

In Tools > Options > Debugging > General:

I have `Enable .NET Framework source stepping` ticked

I have `Enable Just My Code` unticked

I have created a basic example of a custom RequiredAttribute with unit test:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class CustomRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public bool IsValid(object value, object container)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string str = value as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Used by this test model:

```
public class CustomRequiredAttributeModel
{
    [CustomRequired]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the unit test (which passes the assert correctly):

```
    [Fact]
    public void custom_required_attribute_test()
    {
        // arrange
        var model = new CustomRequiredAttributeModel();
        var controller = AccountController();

        // act
        controller.ValidateModel(model);

        // assert
        Assert.False(controller.ModelState.IsValid);
    }
```

The unit test uses this helper method:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public static class ModelHelper
{
    public static void ValidateModel(this Controller controller, object viewModel)
    {
        controller.ModelState.Clear();

        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(viewModel, null, null);
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

        Validator.TryValidateObject(viewModel, validationContext, validationResults, true);

        foreach (var result in validationResults)
        {
            if (result.MemberNames.Any())
            {
                foreach (var name in result.MemberNames)
                {
                    controller.ModelState.AddModelError(name, result.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                controller.ModelState.AddModelError("", result.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your breakpoint? How is your controller created? What are you actually experiencing?

Comment: My breakpoint is in the IsValid method in the CustomRequiredAttribute class. It does not get hit, yet the code must be run because the unit test passes correctly i.e.  controller.ModelState.IsValid is equal to false.

Answer (score 1):

In your CustomRequiredAttribute  change your method to use override,

```
public class CustomRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string str = value as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```